# Extract string from <script> - BeautifulSoup python

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to create a python script to extract some informations from a webmail. I wanna follow a redirection.

My code :

```
br1 = mechanize.Browser()
br1.set_handle_robots(False)
br1.set_cookiejar(cj)
br1.open("LOGIN URL")
br1.select_form(nr=0)
br1.form['username'] = mail_site
br1.form['password'] = pw_site
res1 = br1.submit()
html = res1.read()

print html
```

Result is not what i expect. 
It contains only a redirection script.
I've seen that i have to extract the information from this script to follow this redirection.
So, in my case,i've to extract jsessionid into a script.

The script is :

```
<script>
    function redir(){      
window.self.location.replace('/webmail/en_EN/continue.html;jsessionid=1D5QS4DA6C148DC4C14QS4CS5.1FDS5F4DSV1A64DA5DA?MESSAGE=NO_COOKIE&DT=1&URL_VALID=welcome.html');
return true;
}
</script>
```

If i'm not wrong, i've to build one regex.
I've tried many things but no results.

Anyone have an idea ?

Comment: And your expected output?

Comment: hi,follow this redirection.

Comment: What does `follow this redirection` mean?

Comment: Just post your expected output as an edit to your post

Comment: i'll edit my first post

Comment: Done, i edited my first post

Comment: Is this what you are after `1D5QS4DA6C148DC4C14QS4CS5.1FDS5F4DSV1A64DA5DA`? Come on man!! bring the clarity.

Comment: ??  I think i've brought the clarity. I wanna extract value of jessionid from a script. I have to use regex ? no ?

Comment: What is that ID if you consider the above script? Is it what I meant above?

Comment: Regex is not the only option. You can also go for string manipulation to get that, as in `.split()` function in this case? However, first you need to know what your expected result might be. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
get_jsession = re.search(r'jsessionid=([A-Za-z0-9.]+)',script_)
print(get_jsession.group(1))
>>> '1D5QS4DA6C148DC4C14QS4CS5.1FDS5F4DSV1A64DA5DA'
```

Comment: Thanks you ! it was helpful